# Why am I getting the selenium error 'firefox-bin quit expectedly' and unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, selenium

I am trying to run selenium 2.25.0 on a macbook pro with eclipse. I have created a simple class using the documentation example code. The code errors on this line:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

with the message:

Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022

I have tried downgrading firefox from 15 to 14, 10 and 9, but none of those worked either.

Very grateful for any help anyone can offer! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium webdriver not working with Firefox 26.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897368/selenium-webdriver-not-working-with-firefox-26-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem turned out to be that firefox-bin wouldn't start on the command line either. It seems to be something to do with running on OSX 10.5.

Fix is as follows:

```
cd /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS
mv firefox-bin firefox-bin.original
ditto --arch i386 firefox-bin.original firefox-bin
```

This is taken from this webpage which usefully had the answer: http://www.bangheadonwall.net/?p=296

Answer (score 0):

first obvious  possible solution:
Try another drivers: IE, chrome drivers.
Secondly,

```
 @Before
    public void openFirefox() throws IOException {


        driver = new FirefoxDriver();       
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get(propertyKeysLoader("http://localhost:8090/rms-web/login/login.jsf"));
        doAdminLogin();
    }
```

Often after creating instance of firefox driver you make getUrl operation. Make sure that url u wanna  get to is accesible from your browser.Otherwise it can possibly be the  server  issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I traced it to a different issue. I'll post a separate answer..